# Drupal 6 - Image gallery image popup when navigating site?

Tags: drupal-6

I am configuring Drupal 6 to install a Gallery module and when I navigate the site I see this image popup. Can someone please shed some light as to what is causing this?

[image]

Many Thanks

Comment: Which gallery module are you using?

Comment: Incorrect permissions were set on the image folder. Thanks